# pandas select rows by matching a column entry to entries in multiple other columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

In python2.7, I create a pandas dataframe of the following form:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
'ID' : ['1','2','3'],
'sps1' : ['1001', '1111', '1000'],
'sps2' : ['1001','0001','NaN'],
'sps3' : ['1001','NaN','1000'],
'sps4' : ['1001','1101','0101']
})
```

Thus it looks like:

```
     ID  sps1  sps2  sps3  sps4
0     1  1001  1001  1001  1001
1     2  1111  0001   NaN  1101
2     3  1000   NaN  1000  0101
```

Each row contains data on a different biological sequence, which possesses a unique ID (1, 2, 3 etc). Each sequence is present in 4 different species (sps1-4). The presence (1) or absence (0) of 4 different features in each sequence is encoded as a 4-digit code. The sequence is missing from some species, thus NaN is recorded.

From this dataframe, I want to select rows where the code for sps1 does *not* match the code for *all* other species.

So in the eg above, I want to discard row 0 (code 1001 is same for all sps) and row 2 (sps1 code 1000 matches that of sps3), but to keep row 1 (sps1 code 1111 is unique).

Ultimately I want to put these selected rows in a new dataframe with the same structure.

I am new to using pandas. So far I managed to find a way to do it like this:

```
matches = df.loc[( (df['sps1'] != df['sps2']) & (df['sps1'] != df['sps3']) )].index
df_match = df.iloc[matches]
```

I could continue this style for all combinations of sps1 and spsX, but in my full analysis I will be handling upwards of 12 species, so this is a lot of typing and not very efficient. I guess there must be a cleaner way?

Comment: In row `1`, sps1 shares the same code (`1111`) with sps4

Comment: sorry, silly mistake. corrected now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `filter` to select columns by pattern, and use `eq` to check if the `sps1` column is equal to all other columns, here specify `axis = rows` to compare column-wise. This produces a logical vector which you can use for subsetting:

```
df[(df.filter(regex = "^sps").eq(df.sps1, axis="rows")).sum(axis=1) == 1]

#  ID   sps1    sps2    sps3    sps4
#1  2   1111    0001     NaN    1101
```

Comment: This is clever, +1

Comment: @Psidom FutureWarning: numpy equal will not check object identity in the future. The comparison did not return the same result as suggested by the identity (`is`)) and will change.
  result = op(x, y)

Comment: @Psidom Your code produces the dataframe nonetheless and seems to work, but it reports this error. I don't understand the error though. Is it a problem?

Comment: Not sure where the error comes from. Would you be able to give a reproducible example? Besides, it's a warning not really an error.

Answer (score 1):

Psidom already has you covered with a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42442600/4686625), but piggybacking off of it a bit, you could not include the column you are comparing against and then use [`any()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) to avoid having to sum each row.

```
df[~df.filter(regex="^sps(?!1$)\d+$").eq(df.sps1, axis='rows').any(1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have guessed correctly:

```
df.loc[[df.iloc[i,1:].duplicated().sum() == 0 for i in df.index]]
```

Result:

```
  ID  sps1  sps2 sps3  sps4
1  2  1111  0001  NaN  1101
```